# How to Implement a Sliding Menu in HTML/CSS with Toggle Functionality in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a sliding menu for my web application that contains several buttons which should slide in from the right when a menu icon is clicked. I've attempted to use CSS for the sliding effect and JavaScript to handle the toggle functionality, but I'm encountering issues with the elements not behaving as expected.

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm working with:

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}

header {
    background-color: #222;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

nav h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
}

nav ul li button {
    background-color: #555;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li button:hover {
    background-color: #666;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Taskboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styling/home.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <h1>My New Taskboard</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <button id="update-button">Update</button>
                </li>
                <li><button id="edit-button">Edit</button></li>
                <li><button id="open-button">Open</button></li>
                <li><button id="new-button">New</button></li>
                <li><button id="settings-button">Settings</button></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="taskboard-grid" id="taskboard-grid">
            <!-- Task cards will be dynamically added here -->
        </section>

        <!-- Hidden form for creating a new taskboard -->
        <div id="new-taskboard-form" style="display: none;">
            <input type="text" id="new-taskboard-name" placeholder="Enter Taskboard Name">
            <input type="file" id="new-taskboard-file" accept=".xlsx">
            <button id="submit-new-taskboard">Create Taskboard</button>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script>

        document.getElementById('settings-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            // To open in the same tab:
            window.location.href = 'settings';

        });
        // Global variable to keep track of the currently selected taskboard
        let currentTaskboard = null;

        document.getElementById('update-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (!currentTaskboard) {
                alert('Please select a taskboard first.');
                return;
            }
        
            var fileInput = document.createElement('input');
            fileInput.type = 'file';
            fileInput.accept = '.xlsx';
        
            fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
                var file = event.target.files[0];
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', file);
                formData.append('name', currentTaskboard); // Use the current taskboard
        
                fetch('/upload/', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    // If the upload is successful, fetch and display the updated data
                    fetchTaskboardData(currentTaskboard);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                });
            });
        
            fileInput.click();
        });

        document.getElementById('open-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            fetch('/list/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(taskboards => {
                showTaskboardSelector(Object.values(taskboards));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching taskboards:', error);
            });
        });

        function showTaskboardSelector(taskboards) {
            var selector = document.createElement('select');
            selector.id = 'taskboard-selector';
            taskboards.forEach(taskboard => {
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = taskboard;
                option.textContent = taskboard;
                selector.appendChild(option);
            });

            document.body.appendChild(selector);

            selector.addEventListener('change', function() {
                currentTaskboard = this.value; // Update the current taskboard
                fetchTaskboardData(currentTaskboard);
            });
        }

        function fetchTaskboardData(taskboardName) {
            fetch(`/get/?name=${encodeURIComponent(taskboardName)}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                var taskboardGrid = document.getElementById('taskboard-grid');
                taskboardGrid.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing content

                // Check if data is an array and handle accordingly
                if (Array.isArray(data)) {
                    data.forEach(createCard);
                } else if (typeof data === 'object') {
                    // If data is an object, iterate over its values
                    Object.values(data).forEach(createCard);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching taskboard data:', error);
            });
        }

        function createCard(row) {
            var card = document.createElement('div');
            card.className = 'task-card';
            Object.keys(row).forEach(key => {
                if (row[key] !== null && row[key] !== undefined) {  // Check for non-null and non-undefined values
                    var p = document.createElement('p');
                    p.textContent = `${key}: ${row[key]}`;
                    card.appendChild(p);
                }
            });
            document.getElementById('taskboard-grid').appendChild(card);
        }
        

     //   function createCard(row) {
        //    var card = document.createElement('div');
            //card.className = 'task-card';
          //  Object.keys(row).forEach(key => {
                //var p = document.createElement('p');
              //  p.textContent = `${key}: ${row[key]}`;
            //    card.appendChild(p);
          //  });
        //    document.getElementById('taskboard-grid').appendChild(card);
       // }



        // Event listener for the 'Edit' button
        document.getElementById('edit-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (!currentTaskboard) {
                alert('Please select a taskboard first.');
                return;
            }
            
            // Change the window location to your edit page and pass the taskboard name as a query parameter
            window.location.href = `/edit?name=${encodeURIComponent(currentTaskboard)}`;
        });
        


        
        // New functionality for the 'New' button
        document.getElementById('new-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('new-taskboard-form').style.display = 'block';
        });

        document.getElementById('submit-new-taskboard').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var taskboardName = document.getElementById('new-taskboard-name').value;
            var fileInput = document.getElementById('new-taskboard-file');
            var file = fileInput.files[0];

            if (!taskboardName || !file) {
                alert('Please enter a taskboard name and select a file.');
                return;
            }

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name', taskboardName);
            formData.append('file', file);

            fetch('/create', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log('Taskboard created:', data);
                // Hide the form and clear inputs after successful creation
                document.getElementById('new-taskboard-form').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('new-taskboard-name').value = '';
                fileInput.value = '';
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        });

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            const taskboardName = urlParams.get('name');
            if (taskboardName) {
                // Code to open the specified taskboard
                // For example, if you have a function to load a taskboard by name, call it here
                openTaskboard(taskboardName);
            }
        });
    
        function openTaskboard(taskboardName) {
            // Implement the logic to open and display the taskboard by its name
            // This might involve setting the 'currentTaskboard' variable and calling a function to fetch and display its data
            currentTaskboard = taskboardName;
            fetchTaskboardData(taskboardName);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The expected behavior is that when the menu icon is clicked, the menu should slide in from the right with a smooth transition, and clicking the icon again should hide the menu with a similar sliding effect.

Actually, right now it is static as you can see at the picture below.

Here is how it looks now, it is static:

[image: Here is how ot looks now]

Here is how it should look like, this is when the buttons are expanded, please pay attention only to the header with the buttons:

[image]

This is when the buttons are not expanded:

[image]

Could someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how to achieve the sliding menu effect properly?

Comment: I've created a working example from the code you provided, but it seems theres some code missing, as clicking an item does nothing. Please edit the question to provide a debuggable example of your issue

Comment: You mean when clicking on any of the buttons?

Comment: That's right. You can test it yourself in the snippet editor in the body of your question

Comment: Actually, I just didn't uploaded the code for the buttons.

I just want to achieve the front-end, everything else is ready!

I hope it is clear!

Comment: Let me know if you need it! If you need it I will provide it to you! No worries!

Comment: Yes please. We can't debug code that you've not shown us

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my question :)

The code that I provided is the frontend for the buttons that I have now, but I want to make it look like in the 2 images that I provided. I hope it is clear. :):)

Comment: Yes, that's clear, but unfortunately that's not how this site works. It's here to help you to debug code that you've written. It's not here to write code for you. Your question implied you have already made an attempt as you stated 'Could someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong', in which case if you show the code that you feel is doing something wrong, then we can help you

Comment: I will be thankfull if someone just give me any advices about how to achieve it!

Comment: you can use the translate() css function together with transform to achieve your sliding effect but your code needs some modifications

Comment: Can you show me an example?

And what modifications my code needs? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use translate() function this way. I will also start by removing the buttons. You will also need to add onclick listener to slide back the non-clicked elements

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger')
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu')
hamburger.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    menu.classList.add('showNavMenu')
})
```

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}

header {
    background-color: #222;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

nav h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

nav .hamburger{
    cursor: pointer;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    transform: translate(-200%);
    transition: transform 350ms ease-in-out;
}

ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

ul li:hover{
    background-color: #333;
}

.showNavMenu{
    transform: translate(0%);
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <nav>
          <h1>My New Taskboard <span class="hamburger">&#9776;</span></h1>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li>Update </li>
            <li>Edit</li>
            <li>Open</li>
            <li>New</li>
            <li>Settings</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
```

Comment: Hey Mehdi!

Thank you so much!

I really appreciate your answer!

One last thing, is it possible to make the buttons to slide right from the `hamburger`?

Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Gancho if his answer helped you please accept and/or upvote it

Comment: Yes of course you can play with translate() values and see, for that purpose you can use ex transform: translate(600%) instead of translate(-200%)

Comment: Yes, actually it helped me, will accept it, just want to know if it is possible to slide the buttons right from the hamburger :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have no onClick method on the buttons.
And to get the sliding effect, you will need @keyframes in the CSS.

**Edit**

Read this: https://www.joshwcomeau.com/animation/keyframe-animations/

Comment: Actually, I have onClick method for each of the buttons, I just don't get why you need it :)

I just want to achieve the front-end and the sliding effect :)

Let me know if you need anything else :)

Comment: Well as @Rory McCrossan said, when we're trying it out ourselves we're not gonna waste time writing the code... so you need to provide it.

Comment: Also, no one can help you with your "but I'm encountering issues with the elements not behaving as expected" if you don't show us what you did.

Comment: I just uploaded all of the html code of the "index.html"